# Get access token of a user (twitter api)

Tags: node.js, api, express, twitter, token

I'm trying to get access token for every user who clicks "authorize app". It seems that I have to use **GET oauth/authenticate** ! I'm little bit lost. How do we use this request to get information's?

I would prefer to do it in `express (nodeJS)` but, I can manage many other languages

Any Help?

Comment: did you try [passport js](http://passportjs.org/docs/twitter) for auth?

Comment: Yep ! I just saw the code pin authentication with tweepy from python... It looks good. The challenge now is to exchange data between nodeJS and Pyhon :p but `child_process` `NPM` can handle this ;)